# If no rows exist from a list then display a message otherwise return the values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a tvp of account numbers that I am sending to a stored procedure from .NET code.

If the account number exists in the table then it will return data, however if it doesn't exist I need it to return a message of "Account Number doesn't exist" in the same select return statement as the valid accounts

This is my query

```
DECLARE @TVP_AccountNumbers dbo.TVP_AccountNumbers READONLY

BEGIN
    SELECT AccountId, AccountNumber, FirstName, LastName
    FROM Accounts
    WHERE AccountNumber IN (SELECT a.AccountNumber  
                            FROM TVP_AccountNumbers a)
END
```

This is my expected output

| AccountId | AccountNumber | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123abc | John | Doe |
| null | Account number XXXX does not exist | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 456xyz | Jane | Doe |

How can I get the expected output above?

Edit: Sorry Account ID will not exist for row 2. That was a copy paste issue

Comment: Yes - Account ID 2 is highly suspicious. First, it probably does have an account number if it has an ID and exists in the table - perhaps just not one that matches your TVP. To clarify - does your resultset contain a row for every row in the TVP along with the associated information in your table if available? Or the other way round?

Comment: Use a left join. Forget about embedding messages in your return, that should be handled in the front end when a value is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

If you left join then all null results will be ones that don't exist.

```
SELECT AccountId,
       COALESCE(a.AccountNumber,'Account number does not exist') as AccountNumber,
       FirstName,
       LastName
FROM Accounts
LEFT JOIN TVP_AccountNumbers a on Accounts.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
```

Comment: @ARC -- I'm making the assumption that accounts has all accounts and the issue was he was not getting row 2 in his output but he wanted to.  It is an assumption -- but it follows a standard relational model.

Comment: @arc --   true.  I just assume I can read their minds before they clarify.

Comment: Your join is backwards since the TVP contains the "required" list of account numbers. It would make more logical ("reading") sense to select from the tvp and left join to account table. Or you could use a RIGHT JOIN with your current query.

Comment: After another read, perhaps OP's explanation is misleading me. ARC's comment to OP needs addressing. How would a "missing" account number be associated with a specific ID? There is a disturbance in the force somewhere!

Comment: exactly @SMor -- that is why I assume his data model is like every other relational database and how he phrased it or wrote his SQL is questionable.

Comment: @SMor actually the right join is working. It is bringing back the entire list even if the accounts are not found.

Comment: @CodeMan03 A `right join` is the exactly the same as a `left join` in reverse order, which is why SMor said it was backwards. Avoid right joins, they are confusing.

Comment: It is very simple if you want all the rows in the TVP_AccountNumbers table then select from that table if you want all the rows in the Accounts table then select from that table -- left join to the other table.  This is the standard that is used fairly universally.  Right joins are rarely needed and not often used.  It seems arbitrary at first but when you get used to it, it makes relational data easier to understand @CodeMan03 -- which do you want?